# CoreMedia DAL Plugin breaks Internet Sharing over USB on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, usb, core-media

I'm mirroring screen of an iPhone on a High Sierra macbook using CoreMedia's DAL Plug-in feature.

```swift
var prop = CMIOObjectPropertyAddress(mSelector:
CMIOObjectPropertySelector(kCMIOHardwarePropertyAllowScreenCaptureDevices), 
mScope: CMIOObjectPropertyScope(kCMIOObjectPropertyScopeGlobal), 
mElement: CMIOObjectPropertyElement(kCMIOObjectPropertyElementMaster))
print("Prop + \(prop)")
var allow : UInt32 = 1
let dataSize : UInt32 = 4
let zero : UInt32 = 0
CMIOObjectSetPropertyData(CMIOObjectID(kCMIOObjectSystemObject), &prop, zero, nil, dataSize, &allow)
```

Screen mirroring works fine but I also want to share internet with the iOS device using USB forwarding.

The issue is when I am sharing internet over USB to the iPhone, as soon as I activate the CoreMedia DAL Plug-in for screen mirroring, it breaks the internet sharing.

How can I prevent CoreMedia Plug-in from interfering with the USB forwarding?